# typeof & GetType

Tags: c#

I serialize a class below and the method needs object type as parameter.

```
string xml = SerializeObject(data, typeof(ClassData));
```

I think second parameter is not necessary. How can I remove the second parameter? 
How can I get type of **data** as **Type** ?

Comment: You should name you classes using PascalCase in order to avoid confusion. Just look what happened here in the answers - a lot of people though classData was a variable when it is a class. Conventions are important. Otherwise you will not be popular among other geeks. And that's not fun.

Comment: Here is the naming convention from Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx

Comment: what is SerializeObject? some custom method perhaps, can you post what parameters are expected, it makes no sense to ask for the object and its type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do:

```
data.GetType()
```

which would give you the type of `data`

The entire expression would be

```
string xml = SerializeObject(data, data.GetType());
```

`GetType()` is a method that is declared on `Object` and can be used on an *instance* of an object.

`typeof()` is a statement that can be used on a `Type` without having an instance of it.

```
// Get type from instance
Type type = data.GetType()

// Get type from Type
Type type = typeof(ClassData)
```

Comment: In a brief **typeof(ClassName)** = **classVariable.GetType()** and my method becomes **SerializeObject(data);**

Comment: I guess you could express this that briefly as well, yes.. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
string xml = SerializeObject(data, data.GetType());
```

if you have

```
Person p = ... ;
```

to get the type, you can do

```
Type t = p.GetType()
```

if you need the runtime type of the object. p could be an object of a class that extends Person.

or

```
Type t = typeof(Person);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
classData.GetType( );
```

Answer (score 1):

data.GetType() should return the type object of the class of 'data'.

Answer (score 1):

To get the type of `data` as `Type`, you can use this syntax:

```
Type dataType = data.GetType();
```

I hope that is what you are asking, as the question is not entirely clear to me.